# Does Hibernate automatically create index?

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I have a table Term with a little more than 5 million rows. Each row consists of an ID and a "name". A search with "name" field takes nearly 35 seconds.

```
MariaDB [WordDS]> select * from Term where name="Google";
+---------+--------+
| id      | name   |
+---------+--------+
| 1092923 | Google |
+---------+--------+
1 row in set (35.35 sec)
```

The script from the table generated by Hibernate:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Term`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `Term` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

Java annotation:

```
@Id
@Column(unique=true)
private long id;

@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 100)
private String name;
```

It's so slow to search on the field "name", so I guess there is no index. Does Hibernate automatically create index on id and name in this table? If not, how to let it create index for both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `@Index` annotation:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Term", indexes = {
    @Index(columnList = "name, id", name = "name_idx") })
```

Hibernate will create the index automatically when it creates the table at startup.

Comment: Do I need to add 'id' to the columnList? Or primary key 'id' will be automatically indexed.

Comment: why do you have only one name="name_idx"? Do you need another name for the index 'id'?

Comment: There is a single index on multiple columns, this is what my code says (I took it from our production codebase so I know it is correct).

Comment: Thanks. How does it work for a single index on multiple columns?

Comment: This is more of a general database question.  Sometimes you might want to search by `id` and `name`, but others you might want to search by only one column.

Comment: How does the index affect the database size? my database contains 10 millions rows in a few tables.

Comment: Based on [this article](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46069/how-to-estimate-predict-data-size-and-index-size-of-a-table-in-mysql) I would say you could expect the index to be on the order of 100MB for 5 million rows.  But the bigger issue to consider is that the index could slow down your `INSERT` operations (while speeding up `SELECT`s).  This is a trade-off you should consider.

Comment: Additional 100 MB for 5 million rows? That seems pretty tiny.

Comment: Please review how indices work, and also have a look at how hashtables work.

Comment: Thanks. Good to know.

Answer (score 1):

The primary key is indexed automatically, for the `name` field, you have to add an [`@Index`](http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/app-server/HibernateAnnotations/reference/en/html_single/#d0e2041) annotation:

```
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 100)
@Index(name = "idx_name")
private String name;
```